# How to install Tangerine EGRA tool in local server

Tags: server

I am facing problem during installing Tangerine Egra tool (https://www.tangerinecentral.org/) it is free source code link (https://github.com/Tangerine-Community/Tangerine). Kindly any one help.

I want to complete procedure steps or (step by step installing process) of this tool. How to install this tool in my local server machine. Kindly give me complete procedure. Thanks